# Atom linter-erb failing with "Error: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, atom-editor

I have the linter set to check on save and it throws this error every time I save a .erb file.  In the settings for the package I have both the following settings specified:

Erb Executable Path
`/home/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/erb`

Ruby Executable Path
`/home/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby`

I was having a similar issue with the linter-ruby package, but setting the ruby executable path seemed to fix it.  Here's what my path looks like:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.0/bin:/home/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/home/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/home/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jason/.rvm/bin:/home/jason/.rvm/bin
```

Here's the full output of the error.

```
Error: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
    at parameters.exit (/home/jason/.atom/packages/linter-erb/node_modules/atom-linter/lib/helpers.js:47:27)
    at triggerExitCallback (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/src/buffered-process.js:213:47)
    at /opt/atom/resources/app.asar/src/buffered-process.js:220:18
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/src/buffered-process.js:98:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

It seems even though I've specified where it should be looking for ruby, it's still looking in /usr/bin/env.

Here's a bit more output that's hopefully helpful:

```
$ which erb
/home/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/erb

$ which ruby
/home/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
```

I'm not sure this would have any effect, but for the sake of trying to cover all my bases, I also have this in ~/.bashrc

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

- Ubuntu: 15.10
- kernel: 4.2.0-34
- Atom: 1.6.0
- linter-erb: 1.0.2

I've restarted Atom several times but the error keeps popping up.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
I found that if I start Atom from the terminal, I don't have this problem, but when I launch it from the icon in the launcher, the issue crops up again.

Answer (score 0):

Try pointing the linter to **[RVM wrappers](https://rvm.io/deployment/cron)** instead of direct binaries in RVM which work OK only in interactive shells. RVM wrappers make the binaries run correctly even in other environments and shells.

Simply choose a wrapper directory under `$HOME/.rvm/wrappers/` for your desired version of ruby and gemset and use the binaries from there.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/603662/155887) for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I spent about 30 minutes trying various options based on your response and the link you posted and nothing seemed to work.  I'm wondering if there's a but in the linter somewhere.  Setting the executable path for ruby in linter-ruby in the same manner works fine.  I filed an issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-erb/issues/37).  Hopefully the maintainer finds a fix or tells me I'm dumb with a way to correct it.